# Problems with TicTacToe game in java? using getText().equals() with jButtons

Tags: java, class, methods

Not to sure about why this code is not working as intended and hoping you could help me figure it out. I am working on a tictactoe game from a series of tutorials that use jbuttons. What i have is a method in my main class that "checksforwin" each time a button is clicked. Using print statements i found that my method does run each time a button is clicked however the getText().equals("_") conditions do not operate properly.

This code is part of my tictactoe.java and all works properly. this event is copied 9 times for each button.

```
public void button1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(button1.getText().equals("")){
        if(Main.playerTurn==true){
            button1.setText("X");
            Main.checkforwin();
            Main.playerTurn = false;
        }else{
            button1.setText("O");
            Main.checkforwin();
            Main.playerTurn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is part of my main.java which houses the checkforwin method. The check for win chunk of code is repeated multiple times for each possible win in tictactoe for both the player 1 and computer(player2).

```
public class Main {

public static boolean playerTurn = true;
public static boolean playerWon = false;    
public static boolean computerWon = false;

public static tictactoe board = new tictactoe();

public static void checkforwin(){
System.out.println("testing1");
    //horizontal row 1
    if(board.button1.getText().equals("X")){
        System.out.println("testing2");
        if(board.button2.getText().equals("X")){
            if(board.button3.getText().equals("X")){
                playerWon = true;
                computerWon = false;
                System.out.println("Player 1 won");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

The method will output testing1 every time a button is clicked, however it will never print inside the conditions.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Diagnose with `System.out.println(board.button1.getText())`.

Comment: What about printing out the buttons text or debugging the code?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i put that at the top of my checkforwin method and it printed nothing however when i replace that with System.out.println("some random text") it will print.

Comment: A suggestion I'd put in too is             button1.setText("X"); 
            Main.checkforwin(); 
            Main.playerTurn = false; 
doesnt need to be repeated many times!

Comment: Also, does everything *need* to be static?

Comment: @chris, yeah i figure this is a fairly inefficient way to program this, however i am now approaching a deadline so i am just trying to sort this out.

Comment: Well i seemed to figure it out, at the bottom of my tictactoe.java i declare my variables and i just needed to make those also static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is its not picking up the button text change - after the button text change (`button1.setText("X");`) etc - you need to add it to the panel again, so `panel.add(button1);` or whatever they're stored on

Answer (score 1):

I was taking a quick look at your coding and not entirely sure, but "maybe" you should try using AND operator in your conditional IF statement? For example:

```
if(board.button1.getText().equals("X") && board.button2.getText().equals("X") && board.button3.getText().equals("X")){
            playerWon = true;
            computerWon = false;
            System.out.println("Player 1 won");
        }
```

You could use these types of conditional statements to say either player/computer has won, providing the horizontal or vertical buttons equal X or O.

There is probably a more efficient way though to do it though, but this is the first thought that occurred to me so you could try it out!

I hope it helps!

Comment: i did this anyways as it made my code much less of an eyesore! thanks